# What is the best way to switch off unused wireless keyboard in the range of working receiver?

Tags: battery-life, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

I recently bought a Logitech Wireless Keyboard and mouse with unified receiver ([Logitech Wireless Combo MK220](http://www.logitech.com/en-za/keyboards/keyboard-mice-combos/8411)).
I did not like wireless keyboard, so I use PS2 keyboard + wireless mouse.

No wireless device has any switchers or power lights.  Now I am in doubt: while I am using wireless mouse and "not using" wireless keyboard, is the latter discharging its power count-downing its life-time?
Should I remove batteries or just keep the wireless mouse out of receiver range?

Is it possible to switch off the keyboard (or mouse) without removing batteries?

The main wish is that i do not want to store batteries separately from device. Will it be enough just to isolate battery contacts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> while I am using wireless mouse and "not using" wireless keyboard, is the latter discharging its power count-downing its life-time?

Short answer, yes.

> Is it possible to switch off the keyboard (or mouse) without removing batteries?

That depends completely on the device specifications.  Some devices the only way to turn their power off is to remove the batteries.

> Will it be enough just to isolate battery contacts?

As long as the batteries are separated from the battery contacts, such as using a thin piece of plastic like stores use for devices that come with batteries, then you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Should I isolate both batteries or just one of them is enough?

Comment: Both, even though the contacts are isolated for one they are "active" for the other.

Answer (score -1):

I Use a same Keyboard combo as you.
The store says that this Keyboard combo has auto-switch off when they are not use.