# Does my wireless keyboard use up battery even when the PC's off?

Tags: keyboard, battery

I own a Dell KM113 wireless keyboard and mouse combo. Surprisingly enough, the mouse has a power off button while the keyboard does not. I power off the mouse whenever I power off the PC. But, I cannot turn off my keyboard.

They keyboard wakes up my PC if it's asleep. The keyboard also automatically "connects" to my PC every time I turn the latter back on. It makes me suspect that the keyboard batteries are being used up - even when the PC is off - in searching any probable connection.

So, my question: **Does my wireless keyboard use up battery even when the PC's off?**

Note: The [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/488570/what-is-the-best-way-to-switch-off-unused-wireless-keyboard-in-the-range-of-work) is about a working receiver, mine is about a receiver that's *off.*

Comment: Does your keyboard wake the PC if it is asleep?

Comment: I think modern keyboards manage energy quite well.  We use logitech wireless keyboards in our office (8 person), changing them each 2-3 years,  never switching them off and I don't remember any case when batteries needed to be replaced.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ah, yes, it does! I forgot to mention that. Done now, thanks!

Comment: @MátéJuhász My batteries don't last more than 2-3 weeks :/

Answer (score 2):

In practice, it probably goes into some kind of low power mod, or turns completely off until *you press a key*

Leaving it on all the time, and checking if there's a signal is *pretty* dumb. Its detecting the dongle (already paired to the keyboard/mouse), and presumably pairs fast enough not to be noticed.

Its pretty hard to check that without sniffing at local wireless traffic, but its a common, well documented trick to ensure longer lives for batteries in such devices.

Comment: I leave my rollerball mouse powered on 24/7. The battery still lasts around 1 year IIRC.

Comment: @DavidPostill Mine doesn't last more than 2-3 weeks :/

Answer (score -1):

I think the buttons of the keyboard serve dual purpose: an on/off switch as well as the usual purpose of the keyboard itself.